# Why are these datatables functions 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm new to web development and jquery and cannot work out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 /* initialise table */
 var oTable = $('#table').DataTable( {
      "oLanguage": {
       "sEmptyTable": "No data defined!"
       },
      });


/* test */
$('#testbtn').click( function () {
    oTable.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
    oTable.fnAddData( [ "aa", "aa", "aa" ] ); - throws error
    oTable.fnGetNodes().serialize();          - throws error
} );

});
```

Within document.ready I am initialising my datatable and then setting up a click handler for a button I have on the page.

Within the buttons click handler, the first line works fine. i.e it deleted the selected row from the table.
However the Second line and third line through the following error;

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

However if I expand out the second two lines to

```
$('#table').DataTable().fnAddData( [ "aa", "aa", "aa" ] );
$('#table').DataTable().fnGetNodes().serialize();
```

They work fine, the first line adds a row to my table, and the second row whilst its not doing much doesn't through an error anymore.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fnAddData and fnGetNodes are no longer functions (which is exactly what your error says)

See https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

Comment: thanks. thats where I've been going wrong... reading old documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You use the DataTable API to work with the tables. The constructor doesn't return a reference to the API, just the jQuery object that was used to find the element.

You use the `DataTable` method without parameters to get a reference to the API:

```
var oTable = $('#table').DataTable( {
  "oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": "No data defined!"
  },
}).DataTable();
```

Comment: According to https://datatables.net/manual/api. I can access the API through $( selector ).dataTable().api(); However this is not working.

Comment: @user1768233: Try the `$( selector ).DataTable()` method.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing?  I've worked it out var oTable = $('#table').dataTable{
  "oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": "No data defined!"
  },
})   works.. note the lowercase 'd' in .dataTable.

Comment: @user1768233: That's odd, that is exactly the opposite of what the documentation says. The `dataTable` method is supposed to return a jQuery object, not an API object: https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: Yeah I agree. Maybe I'm just not understanding something. Does the following example which calls fnGetNodes contradict the document you linked to? http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables-1.4/example_select_single_row.html

Comment: @user1768233: Not neccesarily. It seems that there is an old and a new version of usage, the `dataTable` method returns a jQuery object that has some methods added to it, while the `DataTable` methods returns an API object. The documentation seems to have a mix of old and new code.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.